# What changes do I need to make on my VPS server to allow a subdomain to be pointed from an Apache server hosted on another server?

Tags: apache, server, subdomain, vps, cname

I need to point a subdomain, let's say info.abc.com (hosted on server A) to another subdomain info.xyz.com (hosted on Hostgator VPS server).

Now, I have already updated server A with a CNAME, which has already been propagated.

> Name: info.abc.com
> Type: CNAME
> TTL: 14400
> Record: info.zyx.com

But when I am trying to open info.abc.com, it shows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7FB7.png)

I have done this same with many shared hosting services and it worked. But this time, the destination server is VPS, so having some issues.

Can anyone please suggest any server-level changes which are required in VPS for this?

- I have already updated the CNAME on server A with record value info.xyz.com
- I have already created the subdomain info.xyz.com on server B, and it works fine.

Comment: The image doesn't tell us anything.  What is the http response when you try to reach the hostname, eg in your browser's devtools?  How about DNS, have you confirmed that your changes are done and have propagated, eg using `dig` or `host` on the command line?  You don't mention it in your question but have you configured Apache to respond to requests on the target machine?